# Need help importing this github project into Android Studio

Tags: android, github

I have tried many times but every time i do it comes up as an empty project in Android Studio?

[github.com/SmartMeshFoundation/SmartMesh_Android](https://github.com/SmartMeshFoundation/SmartMesh_Android)

I know is something so basic but for some reason it wont work, any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more info about the project, any screenshot or something that you think may be helpful.

Comment: My bad https://smartmesh.io/app/ here is the app website

Comment: Are your trying to import this project: https://github.com/SmartMeshFoundation/SmartMesh_Android

Comment: OMG i forgot to add the freaking github link github.com/SmartMeshFoundation/SmartMesh_Android yes that repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well unfortunately this project [SmartMesh Android](http://github.com/SmartMeshFoundation/SmartMesh_Android) is not a default Android Studio project, so you cannot just import it in Android Studio.

There already is an issue opened on their github project, so lets hope that the developers adapt the project so that it can be used in Android Studio or at least give some tips on how to import it so that it works.

https://github.com/SmartMeshFoundation/SmartMesh_Android/issues/1